# map-detect inplace without lazy map and then detect

Tags: ruby

I have an array of objects. I need to find the first one that meets some condition and return a transformed version of it. In general, this operation could be named “map-detect.”

```
input = [2, 3, 4]
mapper = ->(v) { result = v * v; result if result.odd? }
detector = ->(v) { v } # &itself
expected_output = 9
```

The solution would be lazy-map everything and then `detect`:

```
input.lazy.map(&mapper).detect(&detector)
#⇒ 9
```

This looks a bit redundant; everything I need is to walk through an `Enumerable` to map it, to detect the first truthy, and to return it. Other way round would be:

```
input.each do |v|
  mapped = mapper.(v)
  break mapped if detector.(mapped)
end
```

This looks like it’s abusing `each`. So, my question would be: *is there a native way to `map-detect` in ruby?*

Comment: Your example is misleading. Looks like you have both the condition and the transformation in `mapper`. The role of `detector` looks trivial.

Comment: @sawa it is not. `mapper` will map to `[nil, 9, nil]`. `detector` will get the `9`.

Comment: Mapping to `nil` (i.e, the substantial part of conditioning) is done by `mapper`. `detector` is just cleaning up that result. Why not let `detector` do the `odd?` conditioning?

Comment: @sawa this is a rather simplified example, but yes, this is exactly what I want to achieve: detector is picking the result up. Is it possible without abusing enumerators with `break` and without a necessity of the `lazy-map-detect` walz?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, thanks, updated.

Comment: @sawa “Why not let `detector` do the `odd?` conditioning?”—because that way I will get back _not the mapped_ value, but the original one (`3` in that case.)

Comment: If the condition is based on the value before transformation (as you have after you changed your code), then the conditioning should come before transformation. Why are you not doing that?

Comment: @sawa you might want to try to understand the issue instead of writing comments that make a little sense. The condition is based on the value _after_ transformation. I want to get `9` not because `3` is `odd`, but because `2` was mapped out to `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the example code is rather simplified (and contrived.) Detection is done based on mapped values.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: You do realise that where you test for oddity is irrelevant, ie only odd numbers will ever square to odd numbers :) I also seem to return the correct value without the use of lazy.

Comment: @grail “without the use of lazy”—you might want to understand yourself why `lazy` must take place there.

Comment: Nope, you covered the only two ways to do it. You could make your own `map_detect` that would do the logic of your "other way around", but it would look unRubyish (not because it would be "abusing `each`" - I think it's perfectly fine to use `break` - but because it would need to accept _two_ blocks of code). `lazy` might not be superperformant, but it's the most legible way to do it.

Comment: Unless you make `map_detect_first` or something which would always use `&:itself` for detector, in which case the second snippet is a very good foundation for its definition; so you could do `[1,2,3].map_detect_first { |x| x * x if x.odd? }`

Comment: @Amadan yes, thank you; `:itself` is fine and the good foundation would be `input.each_with_object(nil) do |v, _|` to return `nil` on not-found.

Comment: This is a great question! It deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, purely to detect and return the first non-`nil` mapped value, this works:

```
die "Module refinements need 2.4" if RUBY_VERSION < "2.4.0"

module MapDetectFirstRefinement
  refine Enumerable do
    def map_detect_first
      each_with_object(nil) do |e, _|
        mapped = yield e
        return mapped if mapped
      end
    end
  end
end

module TestMapDetectFirst
  using MapDetectFirstRefinement
  puts [2,3,4].map_detect_first { |v| result = v * v; result if result.odd? }
end
```

Comment: Please change it to use `each_with_object(nil)`. The code above returns the `Enumerable` itself when nothing found.

Comment: Excellent! I've been working along the same lines. I think the basic problem stems from the fact that `map` returns an array, not an enumerator.

Comment: @CarySwoveland call `map` without block (or `enum_for(:map)`) to get an enumerator.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that, but I don't see how `map` could be used effectively without a block. I think a different enumerator is needed, as I've done in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: A different enumerator: `input.lazy.map(&:mapper)` :P

Answer (score 1):

I can see why you would want to do that if `mapper` is an expensive operation. I believe the problem stems from the fact that `map` (with a block) returns an array rather than an enumerator. One solution is to simply create an enumerator that does `map`'s job.

```
def doit(input, mapper, detector)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    input.each do |e|
      y << mapper.(e)
    end
  end.find { |m| detector.(m) }
end

array = [2, 3, 4]
mapper = ->(v) { result = v * v; result if result.odd? }

doit(array, mapper, ->(v) { v })   #=> 9
doit(array, mapper, ->(v) { nil }) #=> nil
```

There are additional reasons why one might not want to apply `mapper` to all the elements of the array (besides it being an expensive operation). Suppose

```
detector = ->(v) { v }
array = [2, 3, 4, 5, "cat"]
```

and `mapper` were as above (bombing on "cat") or were

```
->(v) { |v| v == 5 ? launch_missiles(); v * v if v.odd? }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Amadan for the enlightening comments: we might narrow down the mandatory conditions for the mapper (return `nil` if the input is not valid) and then use the dumb detector, allowing the only block to the helper method:

```
def map_detect(input)
  return input.enum_for(:each_with_object, nil) unless block_given?
  input.each_with_object(nil) do |value, _|
    result = yield value
    break result if result
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the question right, but if you just need a way to find the first match within a ruby array and do something with it, you can simply do something like:

```
    my_array = [1,2,3,4,5]
    # creates a new array for each element in my_array where the given block returns true
    matches = my_array.select {|entry| what_ever_the_condition_is }
    # if there is a match
    if !matches.empty?
        # get the first entry
        first = matches.first
        # do something with the match
        # ....
        # ....
    end
```

Comment: No, you have not got the question right. I was not going to produce php-like spaghetti with `if`s and occasional `first`s.

Comment: So you want the pure closure stuff? you could do something like `my_array.select {|elem| condition}.slice(0,1).each {|result| do_something}` according to [Array#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice)

Comment: The detection, as clearly stated in the OP, should be done _after_ mapping, basing on _mapped_ value. Your solution in ruby would be written as `my_array.detect { |elem| condition }.tap { ... }` without abusing both `select` and `each`.

Comment: Ok, seems just like I am working with an older API Level as you do =) my bad. (the elder versions of ruby dont have methods like "detect" or "tap". then, as I quickly went through the newer docs, I would prefer ary->map->detect, as u already mentioned in your question. sry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Older than 1.8.7? [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-tap), [`Enumerable#detect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect)? There is no documentation for older versions at fingers, but I bet both were there since `v0.0.1`.

Comment: Well, if u r right, then again sry, my bad. Just wanted to help anyway ^^ but as u already found your solution, it is all fine for now, isn't it? Never planed this post to become offensive. If this is how you felt about it, I feel sry 4 that 1.